Fetch client public IP in VB.NET
I have my VB.NET application hosted on azure VMs where it has public IPs associated with it, sitting behind a FortiWeb WAF CNAMEs doing load balancing.
I want implement geolocation to check country of the user, and to fetch country, I want to pass public IP of client to geolocation API who will send me the corresponding country.
How can I fetch public IP of the client?
In case client system dont have public IP and user is behind VPN/Proxy, I want IP of VPN/Proxy.
i.e. I want public IP because only public IP have country associated with it.
Dim ipAddress As Net.IPAddress = Nothing
Dim ipAddresses As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddresses) Then
    ipAddresses = ipAddresses.Split(","c)(0).Trim()
Else
    ipAddresses = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
End If

Try
    ipAddress = Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipAddresses)
Catch
End Try

In the case where proxies/VPN are not setting headers of "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR", then I have to rely on REMOTE_ADDR, which will be private IP of the client.
Considering all scenarios, how can I setup my code / my azure environment to get public IP of the request, either be it System Public IP or VPN/Procy.

You only can get the ip directly when you actually directly connected tothe internet, but usually you use a router, so you can not get te ip adress directly, but you can something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110586/vb-net-getting-external-ip-address#

@nbk this will give public IP of my server, not the IP of the client who is requesting my web page.

Do you have control over client devices (sounds like no) or code (example: client side JavaScript)?

No, my application is monolithic aspx vb.net.

Are you getting any error with the above code?What is the version of your app?

I am not getting any error for now, I am testing my application in Private network and when I browse my application, my system has to connect to that private network. When I do it, application fetch private IP of my client from the network, and I want to ensure when I deploy this application on Azure production environment, global user IP, i.e. public IP will be fetched and not any forwarded/private IP.

Various "what is my IP"-type services have an API that you could get the client to check for you.

@SumitMandlik then i missunderstood your question try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393995/get-client-ip-in-vb-net

This site returns the public ip of the requester.
https://myip.dnsomatic.com/

This command might be helpful,
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com

@dbasnett The site you linked to gives me an nginx 403 reply (until it's overwhelmed). I suspect that nslookup might not be useful within a .NET program. A paid-for API would seem to be suitable if the OP really needs real-time geolocation. IMHO.

@Andrew Morton - good to know.  Couldn't you run the nslookup in a Process and capture the output?

What I observed is, Request.UserHostAddress is working fine for me. Not sure how it works behind my network setup, but it is now working.
